# ToolTip versus Popup (WPF control)

Tags: wpf, popup, tooltip

What are the main differences between these WPF controls? 
And when I should use a `ToolTip` instead of `Popup`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `ToolTip` is a small pop-up window that appears when a user pauses the mouse pointer over an element; the `Popup` control provides a way to display content in a separate window that floats over the current application window relative to a designated element or screen coordinate.

A `Popup` does not automatically open when the mouse pointer moves over its parent object. If you want a `Popup` to automatically open, use the `ToolTip` or `ToolTipService` class.

For more information see: [ToolTip overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754034.aspx) and [Popup overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749018.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Previous tooltips in Winforms were overly restrictive in what you could display. This is why people rolled their own. WPF tooltips allow you to apply a templatize view with color, images, formatting, you name it. The days of rolling your own in that are mostly gone; mostly.