# How can I make a ToolTip for a text box in WPF, Using C# not XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to make a ToolTip that appears, and then disappears after 5 seconds or when the user clicks into the text box again, but if the user move his mouse or over the text box, the tool tip shouldn't disappear earlier than 5 seconds.

Here is my code, I'm checking to prevent the user from typing these characters inside the txtName text box, and when the user writes any of these characters, it replaces them with "" and then I want to immediately show the tool tip, that should disappear after 5 seconds, but in this code, the SetShowDuration is not working, the tool tip appears and stays forever.

```
        private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(txtName.Text, @"[\\/:*?""<>|]"))
        {
            string pattern = @"[\\/:*?""<>|]";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            txtName.Text = regex.Replace(txtName.Text, "");

            ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
            toolTip.Content = @"The file name can't contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? "" < > |";
            toolTip.IsOpen = true;
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(toolTip, txtName);
            ToolTipService.SetShowDuration(toolTip, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is called validation, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7434245/1997232) (exception validation rule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "customized" tooltips of this kind, I would recommended you to consider using a [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/popup-overview??WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for greater flexibility. You could use its `IsOpen` property to decide when you want to display and hide the "tooltip".

[WPF Popup vs Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153807/wpf-popup-vs-tooltip/44154554#44154554)

In this case, you could for example use a timer that sets the `IsOpen` to false after 5 seconds:

```
await Task.Delay(5000):
popup.IsOpen = false;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works very well, I didn't know the popup feature already exists.